# Joomla 2.5 backend redirect to component

Tags: php, joomla

I need to redirect the user on the login to a component page and not to the control panel.

How can I do this?

thank you

Comment: `header("Location: http://wherever.you.want.them.to.go");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than editing a core file which may get overridden if you ever update Joomla, I would suggest using a small plugin for like such as [Admin Login Redirect](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/administration/admin-performance/15076).

Once installed, simply add the following into the extension parameter

```
option=com_k2
```

*Note:* Change com_k2 to whichever extension you wish to redirect to.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to give the user the direct link. Like `http://www.example.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_contact`.
This will first show him the login form and after a successful login he will be taken to this URL automatically.